# How can i changed the IslogIn state in this?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I want to access the setIsLoggedIn function in the SignInScreen. So, I can toggle between the Bottom and Login Screens. How can I do it after the removal of switch navigator from react- navigators

```
.......
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
const LogIn = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName='SignIn'>
      <Stack.Screen name="SignIn" component={SignInScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="SignUp" component={SignUpScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
.....

const App = () => {
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      {(isLoggedIn) ? <BottomTabs /> : <LogIn />}
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Comment: See, for some examples with `IsLoggedIn`: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve it by using a redux store or react context whatever you prefer. So you can declare your isLoggedIn variable at the global level and can pass down to your children components

Now your isLoggedIn variable can be imported from global store to whichever component you need. That's it!

All your children components will be rerenderd which are binded to the variable isLoggedIn

Take a look at my repo for I've implemented a similar one https://github.com/shanmukeshwar03/react-native-todo/